# Correct terminology for when neutral atom is ionized due to an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, terminology

An electric field will cause an induced dipole in neutral atoms when present - I presume that if the field were strong enough the magnitude of the polarization could exceed a critical length and cause the atom to become ionized.

Is there a specific name or key phrase for this mode of ionization (as opposed to say that being caused by kinetic collision) and what is it please?

*I have had limited success searching with "field induced ionization" but am hoping there is a wealth of information hidden under some term I am just not yet aware of (my focus is on generating a positive ion stream).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field emission and field electron emission are the terms.

From wikipedia:

> The terminology is historical because related phenomena of surface photoeffect, thermionic emission (or Richardson–Dushman effect) and "cold electronic emission", i.e. the emission of electrons in strong static (or quasi-static) electric fields, were discovered and studied independently from the 1880s to 1930s.

...

> Field electron emission, field-induced electron emission, field emission and electron field emission are general names for this experimental phenomenon and its theory.

So basically it was studied with other kinds of emission so is still named like that, even if you ionize a gas.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a more specialized term (i.e. related to gasses) but the 'field electron emission' Wikipedia article looks like it should answer most of my questions.